# Why have I my local repository ahead of 1 commit after git pull?

Tags: git, github, webhooks, git-pull

I have done a push to my remote repository, from a local one, then a webhook notify a web service that makes a git pull on another local repository.

After that I see the changes on that local repository, but if I execute `git status` the output is:
`your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit`

Can someone explain to me what happened?

Comment: Can you do git log at both the places and tell if the last commit is Merge commit in the local but not on remote

Comment: Do you know if the pull were a pull rebase?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the command executed by the webhook is a simple ```git pull```

Comment: @Sunil On remote the commit is correctly merged

Comment: `git pull` means: *Please run two Git commands, one right after the other. The first one is `git fetch`. The second one is the one I've configured you to run, or tell you now, and if I don't configure or tell you, use `git merge`.* So you've run `git fetch` and then `git merge`. This exercise will teach you what you need to know: **What did each of these two commands do?**

Answer (score 0):

The issue which seems to happen is:
Suppose `You (A)`, `Remote (B)` and `Another Local Repo (C)` are there.

There are some commits on A and there are some other commits on C.
You push the changes from A to B -> Your A and B are in sync now.
Again when the code or commits are pulled from B to C via pull, if there are any commits on C which are not on B, git tries to merge the code. In this process, all the changes come from B to C and git creates one more commit on C.

That 1 commit is the reason for message.
Please do git log in `B` and `C`. I am sure your latest commit in C will be something like `Merge branch something of something`

Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Git log on ```C``` is: ```commit db89ac74c16a5fbaab68fb9db88ccda215600d44 (HEAD -> master)
Date:   Wed Dec 11 10:05:44 2019 +0100

    Fixed search results link

commit bce25d924535044a76099264a24dcab94c1a8ec8 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: 62974b9e bd22977b
Date:   Tue Dec 3 15:17:15 2019 +0100
```

Comment: Can you tell git log on B as well. Only the last commit

Comment: Git log on ```B```: ```commit db89ac74c16a5fbaab68fb9db88ccda215600d44 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Date:   Wed Dec 11 10:05:44 2019 +0100

    Fixed search results link```